# Why does askubuntu meta show to few reputation points?

Tags: support

I wanted to post a question in the ask ubuntu meta page, but it said I need at least 5 reputation points in ask ubuntu main, and it *said* that I have 4. But, I actually have 19 points. What is going on?

Comment: Your reputation has updated now :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Meta takes a little while to update your reputation.  I'm not exactly sure why, but it does.  In a little while it will update your reputation and you'll be able to participate in meta.